# Is there a way to dynamically calculate the height of a div?

Tags: html, css, outsystems

My goal is to create a scrollable wrapper CSS class that adds scrolling function to a list and it should show only 2 elements at a time. So i need to dynamically calculate the height of a div and then i'm thinking of setting the height of the scrollable wrapper as div height * 2. If there is a different approach them I am surely open to it.

```
.Scrollable_Wrapper {
   overflow-x: hidden;
   overflow-y: scroll;
   height: ;
}
```

Comment: I think you are mixing multiple problems in one. Try dividing into smaller problems.

Answer (score 0):

1. using Javascript

> document.onload = function() {
> var height = document.getElementsByClassName('header')[0].clientHeight;
> }

2. Using Jquery:

   $(window).load(function() {
   $('.main').css('top', $('.header').height());
   });